# Understanding Theorem 6.3.1 Tom Dieck

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, proof-explanation, higher-homotopy-groups

I'd like to understand a  part of the Theorem on [Tammo Tom Dieck](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/diecktop.pdf) p.$130$. The theorem is the following:

[image]

I do understand that $T$ is homeomorphic to $J^n$ with the exchange of the last two coordinates, but I don't understand how to prove rigorously using $(3.2.4)$ that the bottom map with a diagram where $T$ is involved lifts. Any help would be appreciated in order to understand in detail why we can lift such a map. Here's a picture of $(3.2.4)$

[image]